# Visual C++ (CLI) Threading

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, c++-cli

I am using Visual C++ 2008 with CLI. I have a form with a textbox and a button, once i press the button i want the following code to output as follows:

```
private:

System::Void button_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    Thread ^thr1 = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(&Form1::calculate("t1")));
    Thread ^thr2 = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(&Form1::calculate("t2")));
    thr1->Start();
    thr2->Start();
 }

void calculate(String^ val) {
    int j;
for(j=0; j<10; j++)
    _txt->AppendText(val  + Convert::ToString(j) + "\n");
}
```

Desired output:

```
t1 0
t2 0
t1 1
t2 1
```

etc...

My code above does not work. Stating that i the delegate requires two inputs at the gcnew Thead line. What am i doing wrong? Also is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: It is not appropriate to completely change your question.  Start a new one if necessary.

Comment: @Brian: Even though the question might have changed, you answer is still correct.

Comment: @Ben: Yeah...I failed to notice that the `_txt->AppendText` was still there.

Comment: @Brian: I see that Hans put it back to the original question.  But the update has `_txt->Text = ...` which also violates the .NET restriction on GUI access from other threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will punt on the compilation error since C++\CLI is not a familar language to me. However, I can mention another problem.

You are attempting to access a UI control from a non-UI thread. You cannot touch `_txt` in any way shape or form (even just reading a property) from a worker thread or any other thread except for the main UI thread. What you can do is marshal the execution of a delegate back onto the UI thread and from that you can change the `Text` property or call `AppendText`. To marshal a delegate onto the UI thread use `_text->Invoke`.

Answer (score 1):

If `Form1::calculate()` is non-static you need to provide the object that the function should be run on, probably `this` in your case. You will also run into problems that `calculate` takes an argument - the `ThreadStart` delegate does is a parameter-less one.

There is an example in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart.aspx#Y400) documentation for `ThreadStart` that is probably worth looking at.

This is the sample code from MSDN for a non-static `ThreadStart` delegate:

```
Work^ w = gcnew Work;
w->Data = 42;
ThreadStart^ threadDelegate = gcnew ThreadStart( w, &Work::DoMoreWork );
Thread^ newThread = gcnew Thread( threadDelegate );
newThread->Start();
```

Comment: Thanks for that, i have updated my problem (please see above) do you know why this is happening?